# detect when a custom post is cretaed for the first time

Tags: custom-post-types, save-post, publish

I have a custom post type no_resume and when a new post is created in it and a meta that is job_category is assigned to it I want to perform a function in which a mail will be sent to all the user that has that category in their database.

I tried `save_post` and `publish_post` and checked if meta exists in the database but save post fires before adding meta I want to execute that function only when a new post is created not when it is updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can see all of wordpress action hooks [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) - I would suggest looking into something like  "updated_postmeta" or similar for you

Answer (score 1):

You could use the (status)_(post_type) hook. At publish for your specific CPT, query are there any other objects of the same type. If there are none, then this is your first post of the type.

```
add_action('publish_my_custom_post_type',function() {
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
    ));

    if(!empty($posts)):
        return; //There are posts of this type so we just return
    endif;

    //...Do what you want here
}
```